# Primefaces inputText validation to occur on mouse out

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I need to validate the input for an inputText box. Currently I have a button that is clicked in order to validate the input. However, I want the input to be validated immediately when the clients mouse clicks away from the inputText box so that there is no need for the validate button.

```html
<h:form>
  <p:panel id="panel"> 
    <p:messages id="msgs"/>
  <p:outputLabel for="watchNoticeId" value="#{msg.rfeWatchNoticeId}" />
          
   <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
    <p:inputText id="watchNoticeId" value="#{watchNotice.id}" size="20"                 style="vertical-align: top;" disabled="#{!                                       raudUserSessionBean.raudUser.referMode}">
      <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" />
      <f:validateLength maximum="18" update="panel" />
    </p:inputText>
    <p:message for="watchNoticeId" display="icon" />
  </h:panelGrid>
          
   <p:commandButton value="Validate" update="panel" icon="ui-icon-check" />
  </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm9YH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `blur` event:

```
<p:ajax event="blur" update="@this" />
```